# How to highlight a given word inside hbs?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

Is there any way to highlight a given word inside an ember template?

Example:

```
var givenWord = "hello"
```

ember template is as follows:

```
<div>
<p>some text here, some another text with hello, again hello</p>
</div>
```

I want to apply specific CSS to the word `hello` (this word is dynamic)
Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution using handlebar helpers

```
   Ember.Handlebars.helper('highlightMatchingText', function (text, phrase) {
    var highlightedText = text.replace(new RegExp(phrase, 'gi'), function (str) {
        return '<span class="color-red">' + str + '</span>';
    });
  return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(highlightedText);
});
```

then we can call this inside `hbs` as follows

```
{{highlightMatchingText "text goes here" "hello"}}
```

NOTE: i'm using ember 0.2.5

Comment: You should specify the versions you're using, `Ember.Handlebars.helper` was moved to `Ember.Helper.helper` in more recent versions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no builtin easy mechanism.You can try implement the below stuff in Ember.
https://markjs.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.Here span will give it a new highlight and

template.hbs

```
<div>
<p>some text here, some another text with <span>{{givenWord}}</span> again hello</p>
</div>
```

css file

```
span {
 color:red;
}
```